# Sony walkman android 9 BT keyboard

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard

I’m trying to connect a Bluetooth keyboard to a Sony nw-a100 it has android 9.
when I pair it goes thru the setup fine but when the pairing is done it is not connected
but you can see it in previously connected.
also, I have seen in android 12 that it says in device info for the keyboard it has an option input device turned on this option is not there in the Sony Walkman
does anyone know if there is a way to get this working.